# Java "MONOSPACED" font width

Tags: java, fonts, monospace

I'm creating a game and I'd like to use Java's `Font.MONOSPACED` font, because it is easy to use (even though it looks disgusting). The problem is that I have no idea about the fonts width-height-ratio, which is very important. I couldn't find a answer online after searching for a while. 
If someone knows it or how to find it out, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: [I couldn't find a answer online after searching for a while. ---> deriveFont, size, style](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`java.awt.FontMetrics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html) is going to be your friend here.

You get access to it through a `Graphics2d` object:

```
Graphics2D gfx = ...;
gfx.setFont(...); // select your preferred font, monospaced or otherwise
FontMetrics metrics = gfx.getFontMetrics();
```

having done so you can get: (all from the above link to docs)

The width of any single char:

> `charWidth(char ch)`
>            Returns the advance width of the specified character in this Font.

The width of a string:

> `stringWidth(String str)`
>             Returns the total advance width for showing the specified String in this Font.

The height of a line

> `getHeight()` 
>             Gets the standard height of a line of text in this font.

I assume you can figure out how to get a width-height ratio from the above, and you can get lots of other information from different `FontMetrics` methods - check it out.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Tried today and worked just the way I wanted.